# Unity 14.04 - left click to raise window with focus-follows-mouse

Tags: unity, mouse, titlebar, focus

After upgrading to 14.04, right-clicking on the titlebar no longer raises the window. I use focus-follows-mouse and historically use the titlebar to promote windows to the foreground.

Is there a way to change this behavior? I've looked in dconf-editor, compiz settings manager, and unity tweak tool, but don't see anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences raise-on-click
```

There is a litany of configuration tools in system settings, unity-tweak-tool, gnome-tweak-tool, and dconf-editor.  Not knocking Canonical, it's certainly a hard problem.  Rule of thumb, if you can't find it, it's probably buried somewhere in dconf-editor.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please focus your answers on the question you are answering. If you have comments to make please make them in the comment section. If you have a question of your own, please search the knowledge base and if you can't find it answered use the ask button in the upper right corner. Thank you!

Comment: `raise-on-click` is very sucky, when I want to select text on a window, I 99% of the time do not need (nor want) that window to be raised. Also the OP was asking about the `focus-follow-mouse` behavior which includes not having the `raise-on-click`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the window to pop up immediately when you just click anywhere on it, you might like this solution:
https://askubuntu.com/a/171140

I use the following for focus follows mouse + raise on < Super >Button1 click:

1. in CompizConfig: Settings -> General -> Focus & Raise Behaviour -
   disable "Click To Focus", "Raise On Click" and "Auto-Raise";
2. in CompizConfig:  Settings -> General -> Key bindings - set mouse control
   of "Raise Window" to < Super >Button1.